# Is it recommended to use gzip in nginx for a typescript application?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm building a typescript application. I'm using nginx only as a reverse proxy.

Here is nginx gzip config:

```
gzip on;
gzip_types      text/plain application/xml;
gzip_proxied    no-cache no-store private expired auth;
gzip_min_length 1000;
```

Should I use gzip in nginx for my typescript app?